# Is the question pertain to passive voice?

Tags: questions

An assertion in a passive voice:

> He is worried

My question is about:

> *What are you worried about?*

I don't understand the difference between "What **do** you **worry** about?" and "What **are** you **worried** about?" I understand that *worried* can't pertain to passive voice because the verb 'worry' is intransitive

Actually, according to [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/worry) the verb 'worry' can be as transitive as intransitive. And there are [a lot of examples](http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/translation/she+is+worried.html)  with the similar structure (she is worried about)

I found [a list of never passive verbs](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/passive1d.html) and *worry* is not on it.

Comment: No, *worry* is intransitive here.It doesn't correspond with a passive construction.

Comment: Actually, I would say that "worried" is acting as a [(participial) adjective](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/adjectives/what-is-a-participial-adjective.html) here, not a verb. What do you think, @user178049? I would add that the verb is "be" in the form of "is."

Comment: Meanwhile, if you are asking for the question to the sentence, "He is worried, then the question would be: How is he? "What are you worried about?" and "What is he worried about?" would be the follow-up questions.

Comment: Hi, Max, me again. I promise I am not saying these things personally, but they keep getting flagged because you're new and because the question is a little short, so just commenting as part of the community review. As with the other question, it would help if you give us more detail about where you encountered this and about the research you had done first. Here is a link about [writing good questions](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Meanwhile, thanks again for your question and welcome again to the English Language Learners Stack Exchange.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang That makes sense, but believe that it's uncommon. It doesn't fluent to me. I would say "what do you worry about?". Anyway, if it were a particial adjective, then it's not passive, Max :)

Comment: Hi, Max, just so you're clear, per user178049's suggestion, "What do you worry about?" and "What are you worried about?" are two different questions asking two different things. In this case, because your example sentence is just, "He is worried," then your questions would be either, "How is he?" or "Who is worried?" Without more context, we're just guessing :/.

Comment: "He is worried" is a complex intransitive clause (S-P-PC): "is" is the verb and "worried" an adjective. Note that "worried" can be modified by "very", as in "He is very worried".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do you worry about?

This has a more general feel to it.  It could be limited to a certain context (e.g., "What do you worry about at work?"), but it still is ongoing in nature.

> What are you worrying about?

This is much more about the present context.  "You look worried.  What are you worrying about?"

There is also:

> What are you worried about?

To me, this is much closer to the second one than the first, and even further along a spectrum of specificity with regards to time.  Where the second one is about now, but also stretches back in time a bit, this last one is much more about now, suddenly.

At least, this is what these phrases evoke for me without context.  They can always be modified: "What are you worrying about nowadays?" "What are you worried about today?"

Comment: Glad to help :)